# Failing to load tabs dynamically

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net

I'm trying to load the tabs dynamically (using AjaxToolKit). Firstly, when I hit `button1` on page load, it loads `tab1` (works good) and when I hit `button2`, itloads up `tab2`

All these tabs are ascx pages.

In `tab1` I'm loading WebUserControl.ascx, this works okay.

Issues:

1) When you run the code, first click on `button2`, it doesn't load `tab2` dynamicaly but it does when you hit `button1` for the first time.
2) Repetitive clicking on `button1` or `button2` should load the same tabs next to each other again and again but it doesn't.
3) Thirdly, the main issue is that I m tryin to load another .ascx on `loadtab2` which should have webparts in it. I should be able to load an another custom usercontrol into these web parts dynamically. But I am not able to do so.

Can anybody help with any of these issues?

Here is my code:

Default.aspx

```
<div>    
    <asp:AjaxScriptManager ID="AjaxScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:AjaxScriptManager>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click"
        Text="Show Tab1" />
    <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" onclick="Button2_Click"
        Text="Show Tab2" />
    <asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" Text="Button" />   
</div>
<p>
  <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
</p>
```

Default.aspx.vb

```
Imports System
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Web.UI
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Web.UI.WebControls
Imports System.Collections
Imports System.Collections.Specialized
Imports AjaxControlToolkit
Imports AjaxControlToolkit.ToolkitScriptManager
Public Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Dim tc1 As New TabContainer()
    Dim uc1 As Control
    Dim tp1 As New TabPanel()
    Dim tp2 As New TabPanel()
    Dim tp3 As New TabPanel()
    Dim Wp1 As New WebPartManager()

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        'Page.PreRender += new EventHandler(Page_PreRender);
        If Session("Tab1") <> Nothing Then
            If Session("Tab1").ToString() = "true" Then
                LoadTab1()
            End If
        ElseIf Session("Tab2") <> Nothing Then
            If Session("Tab2").ToString() = "true" Then
                LoadTab2()
            End If
        End If
    End Sub

    Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        If Session("Tab1") Is Nothing Then
            Session("Tab1") = "true"
            LoadTab1()
        ElseIf Session("Tab1").ToString() <> "true" Then
            LoadTab1()
        End If
    End Sub

    Protected Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        If Session("Tab2") Is Nothing Then
            Session("Tab2") = "true"
            LoadTab2()
        ElseIf Session("Tab2").ToString() <> "true" Then
            LoadTab2()
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub LoadTab1()
        uc1 = LoadControl("WebUserControl.ascx")
        tp1.HeaderText = "Tab1"
        'tp2.HeaderText = "Tab2"

        tp1.Controls.Add(uc1)
        tc1.Tabs.Add(tp1)
        'tc1.Tabs.Add(tp2)


        If Session("Tab2") <> Nothing Then
            LoadTab2()
        End If

        'if (Session["Tab2"] == null)
        '{
        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(tc1)
        '}
    End Sub

    Public Sub LoadTab2()

        Dim uc2 As UserControl = CType(LoadControl("WebUserControl2.ascx"), UserControl)
        uc2.ID = "control"

        tp2.HeaderText = "Tab2"
        tc1.Tabs.Add(tp2)

        tp2.controls.add(uc2)

(Error:A Zone can only be added to the Page in or before the Page_Init event...)

End Sub
```

WebUserControl.ascx.vb

```
Protected Sub Page_Init()
    Dim Btn As New Button()
    Btn.ID = "TestButton"

    Dim zone1 As New WebPartZone()
    zone1.ID = "zone1"
    Panel1.Controls.Add(zone1)
    ' WebPart myWebPart = WebPartManager1.CreateWebPart(Btn);
    'myWebPart.ID = "2";
    'myWebPart.Title = "MyWebPart";
    Dim uc As Control = Me.LoadControl("FeaturedControl.ascx")
    uc.ID = "control"
    Dim myWebPart As GenericWebPart = WebpartManager1.CreateWebPart(uc)
    WebpartManager1.AddWebPart(myWebPart, zone1, 1)
    'WebPartManager1.AddWebPart(controol, zone1, 1);
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the code out of the Page_Load() event into the Page_Init() event